# Is there any free way to convert 3DS Max (*.max) to *.3ds or *.obj?

Tags: conversion, file-format, 3ds-max

I found many nice free 3D objects on the web - for example on [3DXtras.com](http://www.3dxtras.com/3dxtras-free-3d-models-list.asp?catid=-1).
However, some of them are only in *.max format.

Is there any free way to convert at least the basic structure to some more common format like *.3ds or *.obj? I've been searching for such an app or online service for a long time but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.MAX` is a closed format and the only way to export it into another format (like `.3DS` or `.OBJ`) is to have 3D Studio Max installed in your computer. So your best bet would be to install the 30 days demo version of [3D Studio Max](http://usa.autodesk.com/3ds-max/trial/) in your machine.

Comment: By closed i am assuming you mean encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

3ds max has good export tools File > Export and select wavefront .obj files. 
be careful of the YZ flip which some systems require

Comment: Hello everyone,  I crossed by your question while I was looking for a solution to a similar situation but the other way round. I use blender to model 3d objects and I use Homestyler for visualisation. Unfortunately Homestyler deal only with 3d objects created by 3d max. Is there a way maybe to change 3d objects or models from blender to 3d max? Your advices are highly appreciated.